# How to make a function to go after an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `JavaScript`, you will often see functions which say `document.getElementById("element").someFunction();` or `$("element").someFunction();` instead of `someFunction($("element"));`. Where `someFunction(element)` looks a little like the following code.

```
someFunction(element) {
    //element.doSomething();
}
```

My question is how do you make a function which manipulates the element it is attached to instead of manipulating an element passed through as an argument?

Comment: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#66

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it using [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

```
// `getElementById` returns a `Element` object so extend it's prototype
Element.prototype.someFunction = function(){
   // this.somethig
}

document.getElementById("element").someFunction();
```

```js
Element.prototype.someFunction = function() {
  console.log(this.value)
}

document.getElementById("element").someFunction();
```

```html
<input value="abc" id="element" />
```

---

Note : [It's really bad practice to extend prototype of native object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes).

Comment: It's also worth noting that extending a built in object's prototype generally not recommended.

Comment: @Seth What would you recommend I do? Is it better to leave it as `someFunction(element)`?

Comment: @Dan Use `someFunction(element)` ..... use `prototype` only  for polyfil option of new methods like `forEach, find, some, etc...`.....

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `prototypes`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

```
element.prototype.someFunction = function(){
  this.doSomething(); // this refers to element
}
```

Comment: this function will work only for this element